# How to Get user input from the stdout of for loop index

Tags: bash, scripting, kubernetes

Here is the shell script I want to execute. 
for example, I have 100 kubernetes pods with 100 different vehicles.

I want a list to be generated of cars and choose 10 particular cars from the list.

My goal is to deploy a new image into the selected car's pod.

I am able to generate a list of cars through the array and grep.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash     
array=$(kubectl get pods -n ns -o=name | grep "cars" )
declare array
INDEX=1
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo ${INDEX} $i
    INDEX=$(expr $INDEX + 1)  ## this will make a numbered list.
done
```

sample output

```
1 cars-bmw
2 cars-audi
3 cars-volkswagen
4 cars-jaguar
5 cars-ferrari
6 cars-toyota
7 cars-honda
```

How to achieve selection of cars through either name or just selecting the number of the car?

Please suggest if there is another way to do this. or suggest a better practice for the shell script.

```bsh
while [[ read  -p {array[@]} ]]; do
    echo "choosing car " {array[@]}
    kubectl edit pod -n ns $podname -o yaml
done
exit 1
```

Comment: You haven't declared an array in your example.  It should be `array=($(kubectl get pods -n ns -o=name | grep "cars" ))` And there is no need to declare it afterwards as assigning does declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `select`:

```
select car in "${array[@]}" exit; do
    case $car in
        exit) break;;
        *)
            printf 'Choosing car: %s\n' "$car"
            kubectl edit pod -n ns "$car" -o yaml
        ;;
    esac
done
```

of course this would depend on you properly setting the array first by using the `array=()` syntax:

```
array=($(kubectl get pods -n ns -o=name | grep "cars" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like can help to generate the list:

```
for (( i=1; i<=${#array[@]}; i++ ))
do
  echo $i ${array[$i]}
done
```